# Link Images based on ALT Tags

Tags: javascript, wordpress, getelementbyid

I have a wordpress site and I need the images to link to specific URL's.

The usual "Link to" feature in the media uploader doesn't work therefore I was thinking of achieving this using Javascript.

Normally I would think of doing something like this:

```
var image = document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
a.appendChild(image);
```

But since I can't get specific pictures using getElementByID, I was wondering if there's ways to find specific images based on their src or alt tags.

The page in question is:
[Rockaway Fest](http://rockawayfest.com/intro/)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(" img[alt*='picnic'] ")`

Comment: link to what? why not use the alt tag to build the link inside the PHP / Wordpress loop? i need more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this example.

**HTML**

```
<style>
    img {display: none;}
    a {display: block;}
</style>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000000/ffffff.jpg&text=thisimage" alt="thisimage">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000000/ffffff.jpg&text=nothisimage" alt="nothis">

<a class="thisimage">This image</a>
<a class="thisimage">This image</a>
<a class="thisimage">This image</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image = document.querySelectorAll(" img[alt*='thisimage'] ");
//$('.thisimage').each(function (i, v) {
    $('.thisimage').append(image);
//});
</script>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<a class="thisimage">This image<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000000/ffffff.jpg&amp;text=thisimage" alt="thisimage"></a>
<a class="thisimage">This image<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000000/ffffff.jpg&amp;text=thisimage" alt="thisimage"></a>
<a class="thisimage">This image<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000000/ffffff.jpg&amp;text=thisimage" alt="thisimage"></a>
```